# Converting distance matrix to coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, distance, adjacency-matrix

I have the following distance matrix:

```
dist_matrix = 
          A         B         C         D         E
A  0.000000  0.881818  0.859307  1.000000  0.826203
B  0.881818  0.000000  0.587738  0.368932  0.462810
C  0.859307  0.587738  0.000000  0.173998  0.000000
D  1.000000  0.368932  0.173998  0.000000  0.474747
E  0.826203  0.462810  0.000000  0.474747  0.000000
```

I want to convert it to a 3D projection **such that the order is kept**.
you can see that the items in order of proximity to A are [A,E,C,B,D]
I need this order to be kept (hopefully with distances as close to this matrix as possible, but the order MUST be kept).

I tried:

```
    from sklearn import manifold  # multidimensional scaling

    mds_model = manifold.MDS(n_components=3, random_state=123,
                             dissimilarity='precomputed')
    mds_fit = mds_model.fit(dist_matrix)
    mds_coords = mds_model.fit_transform(dist_matrix)
```

And got:

```
mds_coords =
          x         y         z
A -0.640569 -0.229609 -0.104516
B  0.250715 -0.179737 -0.192425
C  0.095719  0.138800  0.170312
D  0.220188  0.201737 -0.094441
E  0.073947  0.068809  0.221069
```

but when i checked for distances using Euclidian distance, i noticed that the order is almost never kept.
Any suggestions?

Comment: "almost never kept"? Check the results obtained by `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(mds_coords, mds_coords)`. The error between each element and the corresponding element in `dist_matrix` does not exceed 0.1, and the items in order of proximity to A are still [A,E,C,B,D]...

Comment: @MechanicPig but the order is not kept for B,C,D

Comment: Is the distance between C and E actually 0, or is the distance nonzero but smaller than can be displayed with the given display format?

Comment: FYI: Not all the distances in your distance matrix satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), so it can't be the result of, say, a Euclidean distance calculation for some actual points in 3D.  It looks like you would have to increase the distance between C and E to about 0.3 for the distances to satisfy the triangle equality for all triples of points.